# Extract multiple integers from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I'm new to programming and I'm stuck at this basic problem: I have a string as input and it can contain things like `1,2c`, `11,120p`, `5u` so basically 1 or 2 integers (if two, they are separated by `,`) and a character at the end. I have to save the integers and the ending character in different variables, but I don't know how to do it and how to separate the case with 1 integer with the case with 2. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Show your attempt.  This is a Q&A site, not a tutorial or design round-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()` to try and parse the string and check how many conversions succeeded:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void parse_string(const char *s) {
    int n1, n2;
    char c1, c2;

    if (sscanf(s, "%d,%d%c%c", &n1, &n2, &c1, &c2) == 3) {
        printf("2 numbers: %d and %d, character is %c\n", n1, n2, c1);
    } else
    if (sscanf(s, "%d%c%c", &n1, &c1, &c2) == 2) {
        printf("1 number: %d, character is %c\n", n1, c1);
    } else {
        printf("invalid string format: %s\n", s);
    }
}
```

In the above code, the string will be rejected if it does not match one of the formats, but also if there is a trailing character after the match, including a space. Note however that the match might not be strict enough as embedded spaces and a `+` or `-` sign in front of the numbers will also be accepted. The Standard C library does not include a more general pattern matching mechanism. An initial test such as `if (sscanf(s, "%*[0-9],%*[0-9]%c%c", &c1, &c2) == 1)` could be used to exclude spaces and signs but numbers exceeding the range of `int` would still pass this preliminary test and cause undefined behavior for the subsequent `%d` conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great. I was trying something similar but wasn't able to do it correctly. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring for this problem .
https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-substring

```
int main()
{
   char string[1000], sub[1000];
   int position, length, c = 0;
 
   printf("Input a string\n");
   gets(string);
 
   printf("Enter the position and length of substring\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &position, &length);
 
   while (c < length) {
      sub[c] = string[position+c-1];
      c++;
   }
   sub[c] = '\0';
 
   printf("Required substring is \"%s\"\n", sub); // '\"' to print "
 
   return 0;
}
```